# How to add an action to kendo ui combobox

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I'm trying to add a button, like the k-select element, to the end of a Kendo combobox for adding new items but whatever i change the element the result is not consistent and fine with other elements.

Comment: Post some code please, how else can anyone help you?

Comment: You can use conditional template in comboBox: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview to format your "button", to looks exacly as you want. If you put your code, somebody will help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

kendo combobox generate this style for button to open the list.select 
I want to find clear way to add an button to end of combobox like this link. 
the template won't help becase it in control in in list. 
tnx